# Chrome not caching large GLTF asset

Tags: caching, http-headers, browser-cache, gltf

I'm building a webGL app with three.js that loads a number of GLTF assets. The largest of these is 65MB.
All the smaller assets are cached correctly according to the cache-control header:

```
cache-control: max-age=31111213
```

But the large one is loaded from the network every time. Is there a max file size limit for Chrome cache?

Comment: Make sure that you haven't enabled the "Disable cache" checkbox at the top of the Chrome Dev Tools *Network* menu. Also note that browsers might have cache limits like https://serverfault.com/questions/338722/what-is-the-maximum-file-size-that-will-be-cached-by-a-browser, but I'm not sure about Chrome.